# Can I set fragmented IPv4 packet's DF bit to '1'?

Tags: router, ipv4, vpn, fragmentation

If make DF to 1, can I confirm that fragmented packet with DF=1 will go through routers to the dest IP without any reassembly and re-fragmentation?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. The *DF* bit is usually only set by the source, but it's technically possible for any hop to set it, even after fragmentation.

[RFC 791](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc791) states (**emphasis** mine)

> An internet datagram can be marked "don't fragment."  **Any internet
> datagram so marked is not to be internet fragmented under any
> circumstances.**  If internet datagram marked don't fragment cannot be
> delivered to its destination without fragmenting it, it is to be
> discarded instead.

and

> If the Don't Fragment flag (DF) bit is set, then internet
> **fragmentation of this datagram is NOT permitted**, although it may be
> discarded.

That very closely makes fragments (*MF* bit set or *fragment offset* > 0, and *identification* filled) with a set *DF* bit illegal and may cause them to be dropped right away.

Comment: I suppose you could. It's an edge case no one has thought of. Of course, with the most common internet security default of "drop all fragments", there's not much point.

Comment: If so, "{pktFrag_16, pktFrag_16} ---> someRouter(reassemble & re-fragment) ---> {pktFrag_24, pktFrag_8}" can be possible? Where pktFrag_16 means fragmented packet with 16 bits size and DF=0.